# How to deduce what web server a site is running?

Tags: http

How can I deduce what web server a site is running?

I'm interested in any of the details - web server, operating system, web application framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Server:` reponse header will give you some information (sometimes). The `X-Powered-By:` header will also sometimes be filled with PHP version information..

Besides that, there's no standard way of getting this info.

Answer (score 0):

check out this link for instructions on sending a GET request http://www.esqsoft.com/examples/troubleshooting-http-using-telnet.htm

As @Evert says, there is no standard way of getting the info. Programs like NMap will attempt to guess, but it is only a guess.

The page extension can give you some clues as well, i.e. .ASPX is likely to be IIS.